# Avoid "Could not attach to pid" error on IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9.1

When deploying a build to IOS simulator most often I end up receiving an error

> Could not attach to pid : errNumber unable to attach

Stopping build and re-running deploys it without any error.

- I would like to know why this error is being caused?
- How I can avoid it?
- If its unavoidable any faster way other than rebuilding and deploying?

Comment: Faced the same issue when multiple projects were open all had apps being run on the simulator. You could check if this is your case!

Comment: Nope had only one xcode project opened whole day still received the error.

Comment: Please file a bug report with the output from `xcrun simctl diagnose` right after it happens, along with the output from `sudo sysdiagnose -q`.